# How to highlight the substructure of a molecule with thick red lines in RDKit as SVG (high res)

Tags: cheminformatics, structural-formula

I have the following code:

```python
from rdkit import Chem
from rdkit.Chem.Draw import IPythonConsole
from rdkit.Chem import rdDepictor
from rdkit.Chem.Draw import rdMolDraw2D
from IPython.display import SVG


m = Chem.MolFromSmiles('c1cc(C(=O)O)c(OC(=O)C)cc1')
substructure = Chem.MolFromSmarts('C(=O)O')
print(m.GetSubstructMatches(substructure))
m
```

Which produces the following plot.

[image: image of a molecular structure of a molecule generated by the above code]

However the code above doesn't produce the high resolution image.
I'd like to have the SVG.
I tried this:

```python
drawer = rdMolDraw2D.MolDraw2DSVG(400,200)
drawer.DrawMolecule(m,highlightAtoms=m.GetSubstructMatch(Chem.MolFromSmarts('C(=O)O')))
drawer.FinishDrawing()
svg = drawer.GetDrawingText().replace('svg:','')
SVG(svg)
```

But I get:

[image: another image of a molecular structure of a molecule generated by the above code]

What's the right way to do it?

The code can be tested in my [**Google Colab**](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/11_rlM-_50fXnyUVUM3uq-tSt_0pBXsIh?usp=sharing).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code for SVG you use `GetSubstructMatch` instead of `GetSubstructMatches` so only one match is found.
To get all matches you have  to use `GetSubstructMatches` and then transform the matches in one single `tuple` for the highlights.

```python
from rdkit import Chem
from rdkit.Chem.Draw import IPythonConsole
from rdkit.Chem.Draw import rdMolDraw2D
from IPython.display import SVG
from itertools import chain

m = Chem.MolFromSmiles('c1cc(C(=O)O)c(OC(=O)C)cc1')

sub = m.GetSubstructMatches(Chem.MolFromSmarts('C(=O)O'))
print(sub)
((3, 4, 5), (8, 9, 7))

allsubs = tuple(chain.from_iterable(sub))
print(allsubs)
(3, 4, 5, 8, 9, 7)
```

Now use `allsubs` and you get the your image.

```python
drawer = rdMolDraw2D.MolDraw2DSVG(400,200)
drawer.DrawMolecule(m,highlightAtoms = allsubs)
drawer.FinishDrawing()
svg = drawer.GetDrawingText().replace('svg:','')
SVG(svg)
```

Answer (score 3):

It may be useful to work [RDKit's cookbook](https://www.rdkit.org/docs/Cookbook.html) from top to bottom.  I.e., to start with [drawing a molecule](https://www.rdkit.org/docs/Cookbook.html#drawing-molecules-jupyter)

```python
# source: https://www.rdkit.org/docs/Cookbook.html
from rdkit import Chem
from rdkit.Chem.Draw import IPythonConsole
from rdkit.Chem import Draw
IPythonConsole.ipython_useSVG=True

def mol_with_atom_index(mol):
    for atom in mol.GetAtoms():
        atom.SetAtomMapNum(atom.GetIdx())
    return mol

# Test in a kinase inhibitor
mol = Chem.MolFromSmiles("C1CC2=C3C(=CC=C2)C(=CN3C1)[C@H]4[C@@H](C(=O)NC4=O)C5=CNC6=CC=CC=C65")
# Default
mol
```

For me, it works good enough (though in a Jupyter notebook I prefer the output as `.png`):

[image]

Then, running your example as a subsequent cell

```python
# your example
m = Chem.MolFromSmiles('c1cc(C(=O)O)c(OC(=O)C)cc1')
substructure = Chem.MolFromSmarts('C(=O)O')
print(m.GetSubstructMatches(substructure))
m
```

both yields

```shell
((3, 4, 5), (8, 9, 7))
```

as well as the captured illustration below:

[image]

Note, it might be that RDKit packaged for your OS lags a little behind the one packaged by Miniconda (cf. tangents in [this answer](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/6723/change-in-rdkits-encoding-of-inchi)).  On occasion, this may affect some of the functionality/syntax at your disposition.